# how to optimization magento 2.2.1 site?

Tags: optimization

buddy:
   Recently i build a new magento 2.2.1 vesion site, but i feel it running very slow! I first contact the magento 2.0 vesion, so i have many things need to study. 
   Now I want to know how to optimization the magento 2.0 vesion? I have via google to search the methods, but i don't found the good methods. Maybe i'm not intelligence, so i need your help or advice? 
   Thank you very much!

Comment: can you provide site link I will check and provide a solution for performance

Comment: How slow is it for you? My configuration is apache on Ubuntu, PHP 7.1 with opcache + xdebug, Magento 2.2-dev in developer mode with generated static content and compiled DI. The homepage loading takes about 2secs, the slowest page is checkout page - takes about 7secs. I don't use Varnish, Redis, etc. for developing and the Magento app is pretty fast.

Comment: Hi, Rma:This is my site supwatch.com    maybe you can found some questoin! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

<s>Magento is fairly slow to begin with and requires a fair amount of resources.</s>

*"Magento 2 is not slow. It simply requires you to do proper tuning of your environment before it is working as it was designed to work."* - Jisse@Yireo (https://www.yireo.com/blog/1842-best-performance-for-magento-2-development)

I've used the below on sites and they seem to be performing a lot better:

I would strongly recommend the use of Varnish on Magento 2 as it comes built in with the system - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/varnish/config-varnish.html

Any 3rd party modules you have installed require a full review to find any `cacheable="false"` flags within XML on a block as this invalidates the entire page and not just that individual block, more info -
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching.html

Setting up Redis for Session/Cache storage is also a benefit and doesn't take - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html

Lastly, don't flush/clear your cache every time you make a change! It forces Magento to re-generate all of that data. If you make a config change then only clear the Configuration cache. Any product changes you make should automatically send a purge request for that page in Varnish once setup thus avoiding performing full cache flushes on the FPC cache.

**Edit -** Further suggestions:

You can try installing https://github.com/magehost/performance-dashboard to get a performance dashboard on your site and can help you in setting up Magento 2 in an ideal way

Put your site through https://run.mage.coach/ and see what it comes back with, suggests performance benefits for you to implement.

Comment: Hi, Matt: This a great advice. I have see it . Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi @nextion, glad it helped! I've amended my answer with a few more resources that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento it's pretty robust and needs a lot of resources.

A first step in optimising Magento could be using Redis for page caching and session storage.

More information about this can be found in the official docs.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/redis/config-redis.html

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

For deferring JS use a below extension.

https://marketplace.magento.com/bitware-speedenginedeferjs.html